# How to let producer know that consumer finishes work in python

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading, producer-consumer, condition-variable

Hi I want to paralyze the process of reading and analyzing multiple text files. So I have a producer say **Producer** and two consumers **TextAnalyzer A** and **TextAnalyzer B**.

**Producer** has a RequstQueue which contains tasks for **TextAnalyzer A** and **TextAnalyzer B**.

Say **TextAnalyzerA** thread has a task assigned and starts working. Once it finishes it notifies Producer and similarly **TextAnalyzerB** thread finishes a task and notifies Producer.

Once both consumers finish their tasks I want **Producer** to start another thread **"ResultSender"** to execute.

My question is what are the best ways to notify **Producer** that consumers are finished their work in python ?

[image]

I created some sample code here by introducing RequestQueue and FinishedQueue to have a communication between Producer and Consumer.

```
 from time import sleep
from random import random
from threading import Thread


# global variable for consumer and producer to know
RequestQueue = Queue()
FinishedQueue = Queue()


class Task:
    def __init__(self, name, index, value, done):
        self.name = name
        self.index = index
        self.value = value
        self.done = done

    def getName(self):
        return self.name

    def getIndex(self):
        return self.index

    def getValue(self):
        return self.value

    def getDone(self):
        return self.done

    def setDone(self, done):
        self.done = done


def producer():
    print('Producer: Running')
    # generate items
    task = Task("(csv)", 1, "test", False)

    RequestQueue.put(task)
    print(">producer added {} {} {} {}".format(
        task.getName(), task.getIndex(), task.getValue(), task.getDone()))

    value = random()
    sleep(value)

    while True:
        if (FinishedQueue.empty() == False):
            fq = FinishedQueue.get()
            print(">producer found {} {} {} {}".format(
                fq.getName(), fq.getIndex(), fq.getValue(), fq.getDone()))

            break
        sleep(1)

    RequestQueue.put(None)
    print('Producer: Done')

# consumer task


def consumer():
    print('Consumer: Running')
    while True:

        item = RequestQueue.get()
        # check for stop
        if item is None:
            break

        print(">consumer is working on {} {} {} {}".format(
            item.getName(), item.getIndex(), item.getValue(), item.getDone()))

        # consumer do some work
        sleep(1)
        # set done to be true
        item.setDone(True)

        print(">consumer finished {} {} {} {}".format(
            item.getName(), item.getIndex(), item.getValue(), item.getDone()))
        FinishedQueue.put(item)

    # all done
    print('Consumer: Done')


def test():
    # create the shared queue

    tc = Thread(target=consumer, args=())
    tc.start()
    tp = Thread(target=producer, args=())
    tp.start()

    tp.join()
    tc.join()


test()
```

Comment: What do you want the `Producer` to do while the other two are executing? Is it just waiting for them to finish?  In that case, it sounds like a `Barrier` is exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: Yeah Producer would just be waiting while consumers are doing their work.

Comment: Start a **TextAnalyzer** thread with the first document. Start another **TextAnalyzer** thread with the second. `join()` both threads which means they have finished. Start a **ResultSender** thread.

Comment: A thread that sends a request and then awaits a reply is not a "producer." It is a _client._ The thread that awaits the request and sends back the reply is not a "consumer," it's a _server._ You should call your architecture "client/server," not "producer/consumer."

Answer (score 2):

`Queue.get` is a blocking function, you can use it to have the producer wait for the consumers to finish their tasks, you don't need the loop and the sleep.

```py
while True:  # not needed
    if (FinishedQueue.empty() == False):  # not needed
        fq = FinishedQueue.get()
        print(">producer found {} {} {} {}".format(
            fq.getName(), fq.getIndex(), fq.getValue(), fq.getDone()))

        break  # not needed
    sleep(1)  # not needed
```

it seems like you are trying to reinvent a [ThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor), why not just use something that's already in python's standard library ? and shrink your code and make it more robust in the process.

```py
import concurrent.futures
consumer_threadpool = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor()
producer_threadpool = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor()
class Task:
    def __init__(self, name, index, value, done):
        self.name = name
        self.index = index
        self.value = value
        self.done = done
    def getName(self):
        return self.name
    def getIndex(self):
        return self.index
    def getValue(self):
        return self.value
    def getDone(self):
        return self.done
    def setDone(self, done):
        self.done = done

def consumer(item):
    print(">consumer is working on {} {} {} {}".format(
        item.getName(), item.getIndex(), item.getValue(), item.getDone()))
    # set done to be true
    item.setDone(True)
    print(">consumer finished {} {} {} {}".format(
        item.getName(), item.getIndex(), item.getValue(), item.getDone()))
    return item

def producer():
    print('Producer: Running')
    # generate items
    task = Task("(csv)", 1, "test", False)
    future1 = consumer_threadpool.submit(consumer, task)
    future2 = consumer_threadpool.submit(consumer, task)
    print(">producer added {} {} {} {}".format(
        task.getName(), task.getIndex(), task.getValue(), task.getDone()))
    fq = future1.result()
    fq2 = future2.result()
    print(">producer found {} {} {} {}".format(
        fq.getName(), fq.getIndex(), fq.getValue(), fq.getDone()))
    print('Producer: Done')

def main():
    tp = producer_threadpool.submit(producer)
    tp.result()
main()
```

one clear advantage of this is that you have a timeout and error handling mechanism that you can opt in (no deadlocks on errors), and you can run multiple consumers and producers on separate tasks at the same time without having to worry about tasks synchronization.